# How can I match '&amp;' with JS RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an url-encoded url (so with `&` replaced to `&amp;`), but I want to replace all the occurences of `&amp;` back to `&` using javascript. Currently I'm using `myStr.replace("/&amp;/g", "&")`, but that doesn't work (replaces nothing).

Thanks,

Lex

Comment: It is was URL encoded, the `&` would be replaced with `%26`. `&amp;` is HTML, SGML or XML encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myStr.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going to answer my own question, just found it out myself... Thank you!